# How to store a string until find a whitespace

Tags: c, string

I need to make a program where I need to check if the names of cities in a file are in another file.
The file cities.txt is something like:

londres(2 spaces)paris(3 spaces)barcelona(3 spaces)miami (2 spaces)tokyo(2 spaces)berlin(3 spaces)Manchester(3 spaces)Rome (2 spaces)sydney

And the file ckeck_cities.text is like:

barcelona                    miami                        tokyo                       sydney

I stored the file check_cities.txt into a struct and I know I need to write a loop for cities.txt which finds word boundaries by searching for whitespaces, and then comparing each word with the entire second list of cities (check_cities.txt).

The thing is I don't know how to store a string after find a whitespace. Can anyone tell me how can I do it please?

'''

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <ctype.h>

    #define MAX_SIZE_NAME_CITY 10
    #define NUMB_CITIES 20
    #define MAX_STRING_SIZE 100

    FILE *fp;

    typedef struct {
            char checkcities[MAX_SIZE_NAME_CITY];
        }listn;
        listn n[NUMB_CITIES];

    void process(const char *city) {
    int i=0, j=0;

    while(i<strlen(city)-1){ //read all lines
            for ( i = 0; fscanf(fp, "%s", city[i]) == 1; ++i);

            while ((strcmp(city,n[j].checkcities)!=0)&& (j<NUMB_CITIES)){
                    j++;
            }
            if (strcmp(city,n[j].checkcities.)==0){
                printf("%s", n[j].checkcities);
                i++;
            }
            j=0;
    }
}

    int main()
    {
        int i=0;

        FILE *arch;

        arch = fopen("check_cities.txt", "r");

        if (arch==NULL){
            printf("ERROR");
        }
        else{
            while (!feof(arch)){
                fscanf(arch, "%s\n", n[i].checkcities);
                i++;
                // store the names into the struct
            }
        }
        fclose(arch);


        char city[MAX_SIZE_NAME_CITY];
        fp = fopen("cities.txt", "r");
        if (fp==NULL){
            printf("ERROR");
        }while (fgets(city, MAX_SIZE_NAME_CITY,fp) != NULL){
        process(city);}
        fclose(fp);

        return 0;
    }
```

'''

Comment: One very simnple way is to read the file `cities.txt` using the [`fscanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) function with the `%s` format. It will read space-delimited words, no matter the number of spaces

Comment: You write that you stored check_cities.txt into a struct, are you sure it is a struct and not an array ? City names should be stored in an array because the number of cities may vary. An array also allows to iterate over its elements. You will have to do that to search for a city.

Comment: I would simply browse the original file, char by char, copying them in the destination location until a space is found. The problem in providing an answer is that there are too many ways to store the words. You should show us your code and your choices about the destination strings.

Comment: @Some programmer dude but fscanf just read the first string right? If I put the i++ it will read another space since the strings are separated by 2or 3 spaces. And I need the program to read the first city, compare it with the entire list, and then read the next city (string)

Comment: @Cubo78 I'm not at home now so I cant post the code but I can do it later. When you say "destination location" it means store the cities into an array or struct?

Comment: `for (size_t i = 0; fscanf(file, "%s", words[i]) == 1; ++i) { ... }`

Comment: @Cubo78 posted the code.I made the changes the dude told me above (I dont know if I made it right) but it doesnt still working...